# How to pass variables to my SSM Run Command Document from my Lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to pass my secrets value to my SSM document from my lambda function. Though I am able to read from my lambda's output - I am not able to put it into my document to call it as a variable. Please Suggest.

```
import boto3  # Required to interact with AWS
import json   # Required for return object parsing
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

# Set required variables
secret_name = "***/***/***"
endpoint_url = "https://secretsmanager.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
region_name = "eu-west-1"

session = boto3.session.Session()

client = session.client(
    service_name='secretsmanager',
    region_name=region_name,
    endpoint_url=endpoint_url
)

try:
    get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
        SecretId=secret_name
    )
except ClientError as e:
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ResourceNotFoundException':
        print("The requested secret " + secret_name + " was not found")
    elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidRequestException':
        print("The request was invalid due to:", e)
    elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidParameterException':
        print("The request had invalid params:", e)
else:
    # Decrypted secret using the associated KMS CMK
    # Depending on whether the secret was a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated
    if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
        secret = json.loads(get_secret_value_response['SecretString'])
    else:
        binary_secret_data = get_secret_value_response['SecretBinary']

access_key = secret['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
secret_key = secret['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
region = secret['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION']


ssm = boto3.client('ssm')
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    running_with = []
    running_without = []

    for instance in ec2.instances.all():

        if instance.state['Name'] != 'running':
            continue

        has_tag = False
        for tag in instance.tags:
            if tag['Key'] == 'AutoDiskGrowth' and tag['Value'] == 'True':
                has_tag = True
                break

        if has_tag:
            running_with.append(instance.id)
        else:
            running_without.append(instance.id)

    print("access_key: %s" % access_key)
    print("Instances found with AutoDiskGrowth Tag: %s" % running_with)
    print("Instances without AutoDiskGrowth Tag: %s" % running_without)

ssmCommand = ssm.send_command(
    Targets = [
        {'Key': 'tag:AutoDiskGrowth', 
                'Values': [
                    'True']
                 }
              ],
    DocumentName = 'Secrets_Management',
    TimeoutSeconds = 6000,
    Comment = 'Extending disk volume by 50%',
    Parameters={
        'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID': [
            'secret_key',
            ]
    }
)
```

Here, in the above print secret_key, I am able to see the value of the secret stored. But I need it to be sent to the Secrets_Management document as a variable.Here's what I get when I run this.

Current Output:

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (InvalidParameters) when calling the SendCommand operation: ",
  "errorType": "InvalidParameters",
```

Comment: It won't be causing this particular issue, but is the `ssmCommand = ssm.send_command` line intentionally unindented? It will run when the container is initialized, _not_ when the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

The `InvalidParameters` response indicates that your code is not sending the `Parameters` expected by the document.

If you go to the document in the Systems Manager console and look in the Parameters tab, you will see the list of Parameters that are permitted. They are case-sensitive.